# Cakephp 3 - 'matching' - how to filter the data for the booking system?

Tags: cakephp, associations, filtering, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I have `'accommod_units'` and `'accommod_bookings'` table and I want to check the availability of accommodation units for a certain period. For example, Date of arrival: 2019-08-20 and Departure date: 2019-08-27.

`'accommodation_units'` table is shown below:

[image]

`'accommod_bookings'` table is shown below:

[image]

**This code does not work:**

```
$this->loadModel('AccommodUnits');            
$this->conditionBookings = [
    'NOT' => [
        [
            'AccommodBookings.date_start >=' => '2019-08-20',
            'AccommodBookings.date_end <=' => '2019-08-27'
        ], 
    ]
];         
$accommodUnits = $this->AccommodUnits
    ->find('all')
    ->distinct(['AccommodUnits.id'])
    ->contain([
        'AccommodBookings' => function ($q) {
            return $q->where($this->conditionBookings);
        },                 
    ])
    ->where($conditionUnits)
    ->matching('AccommodBookings', function ($q) {
        return $q->where($this->conditionBookings);
    });
```

Their associations are:

```
$accommodUnits->hasMany('AccommodBookings');
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simple you must overlaps booking periods

```
[
    'AccommodBookings.date_start <=' => '2019-08-27', // Here put end date greater than start date <=
    'AccommodBookings.date_end >=' => '2019-08-20' // Here put start date smaller than end date  >=
],
```

Now:

```
$this->loadModel('AccommodUnits');
$accommodBookings = [
        'AccommodBookings.date_start <=' => '2019-08-27', // not match start date lower than end date
        'AccommodBookings.date_end >=' => '2019-08-20' // not mach end date greater than start date
];

$accommodUnits = $this->AccommodUnits
    ->find() // if empty default is 'all'
    ->where(['AccommodUnits.id' => 124]) // find units 124 where not matching:
    ->notMatching('AccommodBookings', function ($q) use ($accommodBookings) {
        return $q->where($accommodBookings);
    });
```

**RESULT** is null if unit 124 has overlaps booking date period.

Using **[notMatching()](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-notmatching)**

> The opposite of matching() is notMatching(). This function will change
>   the query so that it filters results that have no relation to the
>   specified association:

```
// In a controller or table method.

$query = $articlesTable
    ->find()
    ->notMatching('Tags', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['Tags.name' => 'boring']);
    });
```

> The above example will find all articles that were not tagged with the
>   word **boring**.

Poz